# C++ : Recursion (Variables losing value)

Tags: c++, recursion

I made a simple recursion program for this question http://www.spoj.com/problems/COINS/, but whenever recursion happens my class variables lose their value and store the value from the recursion loop.

Here's the code:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class a
{
public:
int c = 0, d = 0, b = 0, x = 0;
int recur(int n)
{
    b = (n / 2);
    if (b >= 12)
    {
        b = recur(b);
    }
    c = (n / 3);
    if (c >= 12)
    {
        c = recur(c);
    }
    d = (n / 4);
    if (d >= 12)
    {
        d = recur(d);
    }
    x = b + c + d;
    return x;
}
};

int main()
{
int n;
while(cin)
{
    cin >> n;
    int b = 0, r = 0;
    a abc;      
    r = (n > abc.recur(n)) ? (n) : (abc.recur(n));
    cout << r << endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

So for input 12, I'll be getting 13 but for the input value of 44 I'm getting 44.

Comment: Why are you using a class at all?

Comment: Why are you storing the (temporary) values in class members? That's just bound to lead to problems

Comment: @melpomene What else do yo suggest? I thought this was the way to go

Comment: @UnholySheep Should I pass all the three values as arguments?

Comment: Why would you want to pass them as arguments? They are only used locally inside the function, so just declare them inside the function

Comment: i suggest you start by focusing in coding a simple function with `int` as an input and output instead of using a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a working solution:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int changeToDollars(int bytelandians) {
  int byTwo = bytelandians / 2;
  int byThree = bytelandians / 3;
  int byFour = bytelandians / 4;
  int sum = byTwo + byThree + byFour;
  if (sum < bytelandians) {
    return bytelandians;
  } else {
    return changeToDollars(byTwo) + changeToDollars(byThree) + changeToDollars(byFour);
  }
}

int main() {
  int bytelandians;
  cout << "How much bytelandians?: ";
  while (cin >> bytelandians) {
    cout << "Corresponding $: " << changeToDollars(bytelandians) << endl;
    cout << "How much bytelandians?: ";
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The `changeToDollars` function, using a simple recursive algorithm, exchanges each single Byteland coin into the corresponding three ones with minor value, until the overall converted amount is advantageous.

Comment: Whoa! Awesome! But why isn't your function replacing bytwo, bythree, and byfour with the values of recursion?

Comment: Got it! Thanks buddy 

Comment: @Karan, you are welcome. Well, IMHO recursion is not properly an easy-to-understand concept, but it often allows to reduce complex problems into a single, elegant block of code lines.

Comment: Guess I'll have to practice dynamic programming then 